# Setting value after returing form in Drupal

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-render

I generated form:

```
function test_form($form_state) {    

  $form['hidden'] = array(    

    '#type' => 'hidden',

  );   


  $form['submit'] = array(

    '#type' => 'submit',

    '#value' => 'Save'

  );   


  return $form;

}
```

After that I have a loop:

```
foreach($ea as $name){



$test_form = drupal_get_form('test_form');



$output .= $name->name . drupal_render($test_form);



}
```

It should somehow arrange that every time when do the loop, hidden in test_form take value of $name->name? Is it possible to do something with form_set_value($element, $value, &$form_state) ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best off passing the name to the function as a parameter:

```
function test_form($form_state, $name) {    

  $form['hidden'] = array(    

    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $name
  ); 

  //...
}

foreach ($ea as $name) {
  $test_form = drupal_get_form('test_form', $name->name);

  $output .= $name->name . drupal_render($test_form);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in hidden value show <input type="hidden" value="Array  Array  Array     post Array Array Array" name="hidden"> and drupal throw a error Notice: Array to string conversion in drupal_attributes()

Comment: You must be passing an array to the function, just change it to pass a string instead and it will work

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve problem, just need to add &$form_state in form function "test_form($form, &$form_state, $name)"